# Does a non-copyrighted scoresheeet exist that I can print out instead of purchasing pre-printed sheets?

Tags: notation

Please provide a download link for a scoresheet for recording moves during match-play. I could format my own but why reinvent the wheel? I am happy to provide a sample as an illustration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have a scoresheet I created for my own use here:

https://docs.google.com/folder/d/0B4uNw3C8V0SDZjZneGVUVTVaNlU/edit?usp=sharing

I have pdf versions in various colors and the MS Publisher file I used to create it.  So if you have MS Publisher you can modify it.

The readme.txt file in that folder has descriptions of the files.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site, awesome scoresheets, I printed out a few for casual use (as opposed to my tournament scorebook)!

Comment: That's quite nice. I like the extended fields for time or eval.

Comment: Thanks, when looking at various scoresheets and scorebooks for sale, and also some printable scoresheets, none seemed to have all the features I wanted.  I wanted the fields for the players names to be big and prominent etc.  Some scoresheets had a lot of features, but the design wasn't very pleasing.  So I came up with this.  Glad you guys like it.

Comment: Personally I prefer to have the game result at the top of the sheet so I will edit your template for my own needs. Many thanks for sharing.